# A 4x3 grid puzzle with one missing number

Tags: mathematics, pattern

I've been trying to solve this but I still can't find the solution, could someone help me please?

[image: 4x3 grid, see transcription below]

Transcription:

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 6 | 8 |
| 17 | 12 | ? |
| 25 | 34 | 19 |
| 19 | 28 | 11 |

and choices are

A. 13
B. 15
C. 16
D. 19

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This looks like a puzzle you found elsewhere. For content you did not create yourself, [**proper attribution**](/help/referencing) is required. If you have permission to repost this, please edit to include (at minimum) where it came from, then vote to reopen. Posts which use someone else's content without attribution are generally [**deleted**](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1348/11110).

Answer (score 4):

The answer is probably

> C, 16

Reason

> The difference between the two first numbers in the column equals the difference between the two last numbers in the column. F ex 17-11= 25-19 and 12-6=34-28 and lastely ?-8=19-11 --> ?=16

Comment: Nice, an alternative characterisation could be 1st-2nd+3rd=4th (equivalent)